# Magento OAuth customer login

Tags: c#, rest, magento, oauth

I'm attempting to authenticate against Magento's OAuth system for the purpose of customer mobile login - there are lots of examples for php but I can only find bits and pieces for C#. If possible, I'd like to circumvent use of a browser and perform the login programmatically.

Authentication and use of the REST API is contained within a PCL library - compatible with .NET 4.5, Xamarin.IOS, Xamarin.Android and Windows Phone Silverlight. As a result, I'm having to use portable libraries such as RestSharp.Portable.

### Progress to date:

So far, I've been able to retrieve the unauthorised tokens; oauth_token and oauth_token_secret through the use of /oauth/initiate but I can't work out the next two steps /oauth/authorize and /oauth/token. The official Magento guide (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html) suggests the next action is to visit /oauth/authorize, allow the user to sign in and then recover two url parameters from the callback url. However, when I attempt this in a browser, it simply redirects me to /index.php/customer/account/login/ - I'm expecting it to redirect to my callback url (localhost) so that I can detect the redirection through the use of the location cookie and then retrieve the tokens that way.

Can anybody advise on how to complete the authorization?

#### Auth process:

```
var magento = new MagentoHelper();

await magento.OAuthInitiate();
await magento.OAuthAuthorize();
await magento.OAuthToken();
```

#### Magento Operations:

```
public class MagentoHelper
{
    public readonly string ServiceUrl = ""; // e.g. http://127.0.0.1
    public readonly string MagentoService = ""; // e.g. /magento
    public readonly string ConsumerKey = "";
    public readonly string ConsumerSecret = "";

    public readonly string CustomerUsername = "";
    public readonly string CustomerPassword = "";

    private RestClient _client;
    private MagentoTools _magentoTools;
    private string _oauthToken;
    private string _oauthTokenSecret;

    public MagentoHelper()
    {
        _client = new RestClient(ServiceUrl);
        _magentoTools = new MagentoTools();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve unauthorized tokens from OAuth service
    /// </summary>
    public async Task OAuthInitiate()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(MagentoService + "/oauth/initiate", HttpMethod.Post);

        string nonce = _magentoTools.GetNonce();
        string timestamp = _magentoTools.GetTimestamp();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("oauth_callback", "http://localhost:8888");
        parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", ConsumerKey);
        parameters.Add("oauth_nonce", nonce);
        parameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
        parameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", timestamp);
        parameters.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");

        var postUrl = new Uri(ServiceUrl + MagentoService + "/oauth/initiate");
        var signature = OAuth1.GetSignature("POST", postUrl, parameters, ConsumerSecret, "").ToString();
        parameters.Add("oauth_signature", OAuth1.EncodeString(signature));

        string authHeader = _magentoTools.GetAuthorizationHeader(parameters.ToList());
        request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Type = ParameterType.HttpHeader, Name = "Authorization", Value = authHeader });

        try
        {
            var response = await _client.Execute(request);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RawBytes, 0, response.RawBytes.Length);
            var queryParameters = _magentoTools.FillFromString(data, true);

            _oauthToken = queryParameters["oauth_token"];
            _oauthTokenSecret = queryParameters["oauth_token_secret"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigate to OAuth login page, extract form post URL and submit user credentials.
    /// Upon redirection, store the redirection url in preparation for extraction of the new tokens.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task OAuthAuthorize()
    {
        var webClient = new HttpClient();
        var loginUrl = new Uri(_client.BaseUrl.ToString() + MagentoService.Trim('/') + "/oauth/authorize" + "?oauth_token=" + _oauthToken).ToString();

        // Get the login page and find the form post action url and the formkey
        var loginPage = new HtmlDocument();
        using (var responseStream = await webClient.GetStreamAsync(loginUrl))
        {
            loginPage.Load(responseStream);
        }

        var loginForm = loginPage.GetElementbyId("login-form");
        var postUrl = loginForm.GetAttributeValue("action", string.Empty);

        // Post the user credentials to the post action url
        var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
        postRequest.Method = "POST";
        postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var postData = String.Format("login%5busername%5d={0}&login%5bpassword%5d={1}&oauth_token={2}", CustomerUsername, CustomerPassword, _oauthToken);
        byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        using (var requestStream = await postRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        }
        using (var response = await postRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            if (response.Headers["location"] == null) throw new Exception("location is null");
        }
    }

    public async Task OAuthToken()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a C# client for the Magento REST API. It is not a PCL, but should work. It uses RestSharp. Code is at https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi

The client is made for backend integration with Magento without user interaction. The login procedure actually does some screen scraping. The authentication process is explained in detail at https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi/wiki/Authentication-steps

If the library cannot be compiled directly to a PCL, then you can surely copy lots of code. And any fixes are welcome as pull-request.

Answer (score 0):

With OAuth1, you cannot circumvent the the login. User has to explicitly sign in and provide you (client) access to his resources. So irrespective of Magneto or not you cannot circumvent the login.

There are ways in OAuth2 that you can not have a user login (ClientCredentials Grant Pattern) but those are reserverd to highly trusted client and I am sure Magneto does not support them

**EDITED**
This how it works:

1. Your app (client) will make a request for unauthorized token along with a redirect url `http://myapp.com/RedirectHere`
2. Your app calls the /authorize URL, the authorization server (Magneto) in this case will present the user a Login page for the user, after the user logs in magneto will then redirect the back to your server on the redirect url with the oauth_verifier. Something like `http://myapp.com/RedirectHere?oauth_verifier=90J98DJ89FQ30F9KQE0R`
3. Then your app will make a call on /oauth/token with all the details below and the server will respond back with a OAuth token.

   - oauth_consumer_key
   - oauth_nonce
   - oauth_signature_method
   - oauth_signature
   - oauth_timestamp
   - oauth_token
   - oauth_verifier
   - oauth_version

Hope this helps.

Comment: "If possible" - I'm struggling both with AND without a browser. Generally I just need help with the standard process.